# Scala aspectj full examplr

Tags: scala, aspectj

Can anyone provide some skinny Scala full example that uses aspectj?
Plugins, build.sbt, etc..

I've added the following to plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.11.0")
```

and the following to build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
"org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.13",
"org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.8.13")

import com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj._


aspectjSettings

aspectjInputs in Aspectj += (aspectjCompiledClasses in Aspectj).value

products in Compile := (products in Aspectj).value

products in Runtime := (products in Compile).value
```

This is my Aspect class:

```
    @Aspect
class AnnotationAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
  def call2Lolly(): Unit = {}

  @Before("call2Lolly()")
  def beforeAdviceCall2Lolli(): Unit = {
    println("before executing lolly")
  }
```

And this is my main class:

```
  object Main extends App {
  new LollyPop().lolly("jjj")
    }
```

The 'Before' isn't actually happenning.

Please help

Comment: Why don't you just go to the [sbt-aspectj website](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj) and follow the link to the [executable sample projects](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/tree/master/src/sbt-test) instead of taking the trouble to create an account on SO and ask this obvious question here?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it helped a lot. Could you help please by explaining how to define an advice that will be executed before concrete method in a singleton class?  In case Sample is a singleton and printSample is some method within it, the following example doesn't work for me:                                             @Before("execution(* sample.Sample.printSample(..))")

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for this topic.